# Matplotlib pyqt Navigation toolbar change background color of "figure options"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I implemented the matplotlib plots and navigation toolbar in pyqt4 GUI.
How do I change the background color of "Figure options" in the toolbar?

[image]

In the above picture with a gray background, everything looks good. The same "Figure options" with a dark background looks like the figure below

[image]

How do I change the background color of the "Figure options?"

The navigation toolbar is implemented in the following way

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

self.figure = Figure(figsize=(6,7))
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
The simple solution is to add `self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color:Gray;")`